# Minimum Xcode/swift version for App Store submission

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

From time to time Apple levels up the minimum Xcode/Swift versions needed for app store submission, this needs to be tracked down somewhere to be updated whenever apple raises the minimum versions,

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/):

> If your app is written in Swift, you can continue to submit apps in Swift 3.2 to the App Store

Does it mean that current minimum swift version is 3.2 ?

I really need to know in a clear way What is the current minimum versions of swift/Xcode for App store submission.

And what if a Pod used by my app has a lower swift version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum swift version is swift 3.2 on 15-11-2017.

About your pods that didn't support swift 4, you can make of the following choices:

1. Check if the pod library that it supports swift 3.2 then you shout change your pod settings from swift 4 to swift 3.2
2. Contact the pod owner to support at least 3.2, May be he had another branch that support swift 3.2.
3. Or you can create fork from the pod then update its code to swift 3.2

[image]

Comment: I think it has been updated now. Any updated information ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can currently only submit apps that are written in Swift 3.2 or 4.

If a pod does not support either of these versions, then you can not use it.

Keep in mind that you can write your application in Swift 3.2/4 while using pods written in Swift 3.2 or 4. This is because the Swift 4 toolchain can compile both 3.2 and 4.

Comment: Any official Link ? regarding Swifr version ?